# Does Oracle have rights to my code?

Tags: java, oracle, licensing

I'm about to write some software for an academic research project.  I'm hoping to write it in Java, but the group I'm working with raised some concerns about licensing.  I originally though these were silly questions, but I'm having trouble finding definitive answers:

If I write software in Java, am I free to release that software and its source code?  Are there restrictions on how I can license it?  Does Oracle have any rights to it?

Comment: What does the license agreement say?

Comment: Thousands of businesses rely on the fact that Oracle does _not_ claim rights on their code. This seems like a _de facto_ non-issue to me.

Comment: Yeah, I've been writing and distributing java for over 13 years, Oracle has been at the helm a few years now, but its still the same. Your source is your source.

Comment: This is a nice change from.  *"I want to change some source for a Jar I got, you don't need to know where it came from."*  +1 for the ethics of the group.  (But yeah, as noted, there are no conditions/requirement on revealing your own source.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I write software in Java, am I free to release that software and its source code?

Absolutely.

> Are there restrictions on how I can license it?

None whatsoever.  (Or at least, not based on the fact that it is written in Java.)

> Does Oracle have any rights to it?

No.

The only (possibly) relevant rights Oracle have are to do with your distributing modified versions of the Java platform ... or using the Java trademarks inappropriately.

> ... but the group I'm working with raised some concerns about licensing.

It is safe to say that the people who raised those concerns haven't got a clue.

Answer (score 5):

No Oracle does not have rights to your code. It will be your software.

Comment: But what if your software includes an implementation of `rangeCheck`?

Comment: @ta.speot.is - If it is **your** implementation of `rangeCheck` there are no concerns.  If you are redistributing an unmodified copy of an Oracle JRE, there are no concerns.  (It is expressly permitted.)  If you start copying Oracle source code into your code-base, then it depends on where you got the code from.  (The OpenJDK source code is GPL.  That wouldn't give Oracle rights to your code, but it may constrain the way that you can distribute it.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a lawyer; I'd recommend that you get one to be sure.

With that said, I think the concern is overblown.    Everyone who writes a Java application is not obligated to turn over source to Oracle or anyone else.

It makes no sense - how could Java have been so widely adopted if that were the case?